# How to upgrade Nginx?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I'm on Ububtu and I'm trying upgrade Nginx 1.0.5 to the latest version 1.2.6. Here's what I did and what didn't work.

```
$ nginx -v
nginx: nginx version: nginx/1.0.5
$ curl -O http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.2.6.tar.gz
$ tar xvzf nginx-1.2.6.tar.gz
$ cd nginx-1.2.6/
$ ./configure
$ make && sudo make install

$ nginx -v
nginx: nginx version: nginx/1.0.5 <<< still old version!!!
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: As gertvdijk says, use the PPA and install it as a package instead of compiling it yourself: http://wiki.nginx.org/Install#Ubuntu_PPA

Answer (score 6):

Please, please, don't compile from source if you don't have to. `make install` overwrites files on your system and may confuse your package management. Besides, Nginx provides official repositories for Ubuntu for your convenience [on their website](http://nginx.org/en/download.html)<sup>1</sup>. Also, the [Nginx team on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~nginx) provides PPAs for Ubuntu (both stable & development).

<sup>1 Thanks to [VBart](https://serverfault.com/users/120807/vbart) for pointing this out.</sup>

Comment: The official nginx repository for Ubuntu is here: http://nginx.org/en/download.html

Answer (score 3):

You probably have Nginx in two different places and your $PATH env is picking up the old one. Run `which nginx` to find out which it's picking up.

My guess is it is picking up one in `/usr/sbin/nginx` and since you didn't put a `--prefix=/usr` in your `./configure` line it is installing 1.2.6 in `/usr/local/sbin/nginx`

Comment: My current version is installed at `/usr/sbin/nginx` but it didn't install anything in `/usr/local/sbin`.

Comment: Ahh... found it. It's in `/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx`. If I just `rm -rf /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx` will that take care of that, or is there anything else I need to remove?

Comment: I expect the whole /usr/local/nginx tree can go if you want to remove it rather than use it. Personally I'd go with the PPA method (see other answer), but if you do want a custom compile then using it from where it is should be fine, just need to specify the full path.

Comment: So I basically need to remove my current version and install with `apt-get`. Is that what you're saying?

Comment: yes, but probably need to activate the ppa first if you want v 1.2.6. On 12.04 you will get v 1.1.19 without the ppa. No idea which version you will get in the ppa or on 12.10.